# Make grep print missing queries

Tags: grep

I'm using grep -f and would like to make grep print also lines in file 1 that are missing in file 2:

file1:

```
hello
my
name
is
bernardo
```

file 2:

```
hello 1
my 2
name 3
is 4
```

ideal output:

```
hello 1
my 2
name 3
is 4
bernardo
```

Comment: Please share what you have done/tried so far !

Answer (score 2):

This will print the lines in file2 that are not in file1:

```
fgrep -F -x -v -f file1 file2
```

The -F means to treat the input as fixed strings rather than patterns, the -x means to match the whole line, the -v means to print lines that don't match rather than those that do match, and -f file1 uses file1 as a list of patterns.

Your question is kind of unclear but I'm guessing that you want all of the lines that appear in one or the other file but not both.  There's several ways to do that.  One is to do two greps:

```
fgrep -F -x -v -f file2 file1; fgrep -F -x -v -f file1 file2
```

Another, if the order of the lines in the output doesn't matter, is to sort
them and use comm:

```
sort file1 -o sortfile1
sort file2 -o sortfile2
comm -3 sortfile1 sortfile2
```

Comment: As I understand it, OP wants to print lines from `file2` that are matches for lines in `file1` *and* lines from `file1` that have no matches in `file2`.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -f file1 file2 && grep -o -f file1 file2 | sed s'/^\(.*\)$/-e "\1"/g' | tr '\n' ' ' | xargs grep -v file1
```

What this does is print all matches from *file2* by patterns in *file1*, and after that print all lines from *file1* that do not match files in *file2*. The second part is done as follows:

- `grep -o -f file1 file2` returns matches between *file* and *file2*, but only the matching parts of the lines;
- `sed s'/^\(.*\)$/-e "\1"/g' | "\1"/g' | tr '\n' ' '` prefixes those matching parts with `-e`, encases them in double quotes, and replaces newlines printed by the `grep -f` command with spaces. This builds a string of the form `-e "[pattern1]" -e "[pattern2]" ...`, which is what `grep` uses for multiple patterns matching. The quotes (hopefully) ensure that spaces in patterns will not be a problem;
- `xargs grep -v file1` builds and executes the command `grep -v file1 [whatever was piped to xargs]`. The result is all lines from *file1* that have not match in the output of the first command (and, thus, in *file2*).

I'm not completely sure this solves your problem since non-matching lines from *file1* are printed at the end (by far the easiest option), and you do not say where you want them. It probably could be done more elegantly, too.

Here's a sample output:

```
sh-4.3$ cat file1
hello
my
name
is
bernardo

sh-4.3$ cat file2
hello 1
my 2
name 3
is 4

sh-4.3$ grep -f file1 file2 && grep -o -f file1 file2 | sed s'/^\(.*\)$/-e "\1"/g' | tr '\n' ' ' | xargs grep -v file1
hello 1
my 2
name 3
is 4
bernardo
```